# how to make sharp gradient drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable

i want to make a sharp black and white gradient like this 
[image]

all i did is this

[image]

this is my drawable file

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#000"
    android:endColor="#fff"
    android:centerColor="#fff"
    />
</shape>
```

any idea how to make it!

Comment: Then you don't want a **gradient** at all. You only want 2 colors - without a transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others already noticed, the effect you want to achive isn't a gradient.
If I understand you are trying to achieve **flexible** image, **divided 1:1**.

Getting this is **not possible** neither via *.xml* file nor via *9patch* (then you lose sharp transition between black and white).

First solution is to use `LinearLayout` and `layout_weight`s. You can add a *'layer'* to your layout - if it would be background - under other components. This *'layer'* looks like that:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you use it once or twice in your layout this additional/nested layout would not be a problem, but avoid such solutions inside collection items.

---

You can also try with ordinary ***two-color png file*** and `ImageView`. 
(Tip: Suitable dimensions of this file can give you sharp transition.)

---

Third way to do it, the **lightest** one, but a little time consuming is to **override [View.onDraw()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)) method** and paint both halves before other content would be drawn.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great website for this, just go there and change to 'android' tab. 
Here is the link: [Angrytools.com](http://angrytools.com/gradient/)

Comment: this is very good answer and good aid to memory , Vote Up , but for link based answer you can add them as comment .

Comment: Sure, next time this is what i will do.

Comment: @Sarah Guys, did you make this shape? That would be very revealing for me, but I still can't get those effect. I get this: 
[unique link](http://angrytools.com/gradient/?51_FFFFFF,50_000000&100_100,0_100&l_0). Suggested gradients do not resemble the result...

Answer (score 1):

First of all as per you image this contains black color only . So you can use simple solid to do this 
as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#000000" />

</shape>
```

Comment: its black and white but its double width the second image .